# Trouble testing Twitter API from Delphi's REST Debugger

Tags: rest, delphi, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

Today, juggling Twitter accounts, accidentally deleted an app that was working Ok for two years. Tried to recreate it using REST Debugger in Delphi Alexandria 11.3, and so far I have failed. This is what I have done so far:

1. First I create a project and an app in Twitter Developer dashboard. For the app I only create it, not touching "User authentication settings" at all; that's because I'm using PIN based OAuth (the PIN is the Auth-code), and filling "User authentication settings" forces me to fill callback URI, and that means I don't get the PIN.
2. Then in REST Debugger I set Authentication to OAuth, open the Wizard, fill in values, go through the process, everything gets generated just fine, tokens, everything.
3. Back from the Wizard when I try to test whatever is permitted, say, sending a tweet, I get a 403 ("Your client app is not configured with the appropriate oauth1 app permissions for this endpoint"). So I go back to the Twitter Dev dashboard and to "User authentication settings" (which by the way gives me new Client ID and Client Secret), and have to select permissions, but I also have to fill in callback URI, because it is required.
4. I also tried to use Bearer token auth, it is disabled by now in Twitter API.

This is where I'm lost. I want to use oob (out-of-band auth), that is, like PIN based, but that damn callback URI gets me confused.

This wasn't like this not so long ago, I suppose something changed recently.

Does anybody know if I can still test Twitter API from the REST Debugger, and how it has to be configured to do so?